# Incrustar PDF con base64 y PHP mayor a 6MB en un html

Tags: php, html, pdf, base64

Tengo el siguiente problema, necesito generar un html con un pdf incrustado dentro de un embed, lo interesante es que con archivos menores a 6MB no hay ningún problema pero cuando el archivo es mas grande falla  y solo aparece una pantalla blanca.

¿Como lo hago para que aparezca el archivo mas grande igual que el pequeño?

Acepto todo tipo de sugerencias.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

```
    $src = urldecode($_REQUEST['archivo']);
    //$src <-- string 'Z:/327000360.pdf'

    ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
    $dataBase64 = base64_encode(file_get_contents($src));        

    $html = "<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='UTF-8'>
        <title>Visor de PDF</title>
        <style>
            html,body{
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            embed{
                height: 99vh;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <embed src='data:application/pdf;base64,$dataBase64' width='100%' type='application/pdf'>   
    </body>
    </html>";

    echo $html;
```

Comment: Te sucede esto en localhost?

Comment: si y también en producción

Comment: si ahi te lo respondi pero al parecer no es eso

Answer (score 1):

Generalmente este problema sucede debido a que el tiempo que tarda en ejecutarse tu script excede el tiempo máximo por defecto programado en el **PHP.ini** provocando así la detención abrupta de la ejecución del script.

Para solucionar esto puedes utilizar la instrucción `set_time_limit(300);` dentro de tu archivo. Esto te permite ejecutar un **script** (en tu caso la carga de un archivo **PDF** de mayor tamaño) por un tiempo de **300 segundos** o lo que es lo mismo **5 minutos**. Si deseas colocar un tiempo mayor a 300 segundos debes cambiar otros parametros disponibles en el **.conf** del servidor como lo muestra esta respuesta a un usuario de StackOverflow página inglesa: [PHP set_time_limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43996862/php-set-time-limit-generates-timeout-on-php-fpm).

Tu código quedaría así (aunque preferiblemente colocar el set time limit al inicio del archivo **.php**):

```
set_time_limit(300); // Esta es la línea añadida para lograr tu objetivo.
$src = urldecode($_REQUEST['archivo']);
    //$src <-- string 'Z:/327000360.pdf'

    ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
    $dataBase64 = base64_encode(file_get_contents($src));        

    $html = "<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='UTF-8'>
        <title>Visor de PDF</title>
        <style>
            html,body{
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            embed{
                height: 99vh;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <embed src='data:application/pdf;base64,$dataBase64' width='100%' type='application/pdf'>   
    </body>
    </html>";

    echo $html;
```

Espero sea de utilidad. Un Saludo!

Comment: Hola buenas tardes, graacias por tu respuesta, estuve probando un rato con sleep() y pude descartar que sea un error de tiempo de ejecución aunque creo que si es un problema de limitación de recursos... pero no se como arreglarlo, lo que si puedo decir es que el error se produce en la linea: base64_encode(file_get_contents($src)); no se cual de las dos funciones serán pero no traen todos los datos que contiene el archivo.

Comment: Es lo que se me ha ocurrido. Si se algo más actualizo mi respuesta

Comment: gracias compañero... te aviso si logro solucionar el problema aunque estaba pensando en hacer una copia del archivo en la carpeta public y luego de que el usuario lo haya visto borrarlopara evitar archivos temporales innecesarios (que era en origen el objetivo...). Un saludo!

Comment: Ok. Espero puedas solucionarlo pronto. Un Saludo Renato!